# Rails Need help to capture form field in model from product view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

**I need to capture a field added by a user in a form_for, inside the product show page.**

My product.rb model as follows:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :complaints
```

My complaint.rb model as follows:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :user
```

My user.rb model as follows:

```
has_many :products
```

My product controller is a basic controller with all the new, create, edit, update actions and all the routes are good.

User looks at the product show page like this, and it's all good

http://localhost:3000/products/1

**My goal is to create a complaint from the product show page, when user views the specific product. So I have created a complaints_controller.rb to capture all the details of the product, and create a complaint. I have an issue with capturing the complaint_number which is a field inside the complaints table.**

**Here is my form inside the product show page**

```
<%= form_for([@product, @product.complaints.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :complaint_number, placeholder: "Enter complaint number you were given" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Complaint' %>
<% end %>
```

**Here is my complaints_controller.rb**

Goal is to capture the complaint_number fields and run the make_complaint method to create a complaint and populate rest of the fields in the newly created row of the complains table.

```
class ComplaintsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def create

    # Will Get product_id from the action in the form in product show page.
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    # This complaint_number does not seem to work
    complaint_number = product.complaints.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])

    # Now I want to run a make_complaint method and pass the product and the complaint number. This fails, I can't capture the complaint_number in the form from user input.
    make_complaint(product, complaint_number) 
    redirect_to request.referrer

  end

  private

    def make_complaint(product, complaint_number)
      
      complaint = product.complaints.new
      complaint.title = product.title
      complaint.owner_name = product.user.name
      complaint.owner_id = product.user.id
      
      # Note: complaint_number and current_complaint are a fields in the Orders table
      # Note: 
      complaint.current_complaint = complaint_number

      if complaint.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your complaint has been sent!"
      else
        flash[:alert] = complaint.errors.full_messages
      end

    end

end
```

For routes I have added `resources :complaint, only: [:create]` inside the resources of products to get products/:id/complaints

My routes.rb is like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  get 'products/new'
  get 'products/create'
  get 'products/edit'
  get 'products/update'
  get 'products/show'
  root 'pages#home'

  get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show'

  post '/users/edit', to: 'users#update'

  resources :products do
    member do 
      delete :remove_image
      post :upload_image
    end
    resources :complaint, only: [:create]
  end

  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_up: 'register', sign_out: 'logout', edit: 'profile' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form has `complaint_quantity`:

```rb
<%= form_for([@product, @product.complaints.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :complaint_quantity, placeholder: "Enter complaint number you were given" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Complaint' %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller has `complaint_number`:

```rb
complaint_number = product.complaints.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])
```

If you check your params from the server log, I bet you'll see the value you are looking for is coming across as `complaint_quantity` and not `complaint_number`.

**UPDATE**

With the form misspelling corrected, the error persists, so let's check into more areas:

`complaint_number = product.complaints.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])`

So, break that down:

##### 1. What does `params` actually include?

Is `:complaint_number` being submitted from the form?
If not, the form still has an error somewhere.

##### 2. Does `product.complaints` actually include a complaint that could be matched by `complaint_number`?

I don't know your data structure well enough to tell, but it looks to me like you might actually want to do:

`Complaint.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])`

instead of:

`products.complaints.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])`

**UPDATE #2**

You know the problem is with your params.

I'm confident you aren't accessing your params correctly since you are using a nested form:

```rb
form_for([@product, @product.complaints.new])
```

Should mean your params are structured like `{ product: { complaint: { complaint_number: 1234 }}}`

So `params[: complaint_number]` is `nil` because it should really be something like `params[:product][:complaint][:complaint_number]`

Please look at your server log in your terminal right after you submit the form to see the structure of your params. Or insert a debugger in the controller action and see what `params` returns.

ALSO, Instead of accessing `params` directly, you should whitelist params as a private method in your controller.

Something along these lines:

```rb
private

def product_complaint_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, complaint_params: [ :complaint_number ])

end
```

See this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: So basically my compliant_number from the form is nil and in the controller I am storing complaint_number inside current_complaint. Both of these fields belong to the Complaints Table. I have removed the if else statement from the create action, to run the make_complaint method.

Comment: Chiperific, thanks so much for looking into my issue and helping me out here. So you're right. I made a mistake on the form. it's supposed to be complaint_number. This is a mistake. I have fixed it now but I sitll have the same problem. I get nil for complaint number . In debug console I did this: >> complaint #<Complaint id: nil, title: "Lentils", current_complaint: nil, user_name: "Joe Smith", product_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, complaint_number: nil> I will have fixed my question from complaint_quantity to complaint_number

Comment: See update. Please post the server log entry just after the form is submitted, this will tell us what values are being sent to the controller.

Comment: Sorry earlier i tried to use my orders controller logic to make it work. I think my problem is with this 
complaint_number = product.complaints.find_by(complaint_number: params[:complaint_number])

Comment: See update. I address the potential issues with that line of code. It's either the `params` or it's `products.complaints`

Comment: Your suggestions did help me out in getting closer. There is definitely something wrong with params. Also form, the form is wrong, The form instantiates, then complaints_controller runs create action, complaint is created and form fails to capture the field. I am missing a step somewhere. like you said I need to instantiate and create in the orders_controller and fix the form. But how will I get the product_id now? maybe a session?

Comment: I am getting all the values from the product table at this point using product_id. Then filling the fields of the complaint table using the make_complaint method(product, complaint_number), the second parameter isn't being captured. The product values are fine, because they already exist in the DB.

Comment: See my update. You don't need to abandon the work you've got in the product controller, I think you just need a better understanding of how to access values in a param.

Comment: ALSO! Does your products model have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints`

Comment: Actually no, it does not have accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints because the complaints is a special case. It's just a number that a user must input in a form, it will never be an array of numbers, or a hash of key, value pairs. So I did not used accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: What I mean is the complaints table is just a simple table. It's create by a user when the user inputs a complaint_number inside the form, of which is in the product show page. The the complaints tables's fields get filled with the product title as the complaint title, owner_id which is the product owners ID etc.. I get all these variables from the product. But I can't seem to get the complaint_number which is the user input inside the form_for in the product show page. I am lost.

Comment: Wow you are so right. I followed your update and working on it now. This is what params got me in debugger. 

**<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"765ipol1Dp/YYHI1LpOZDsQs29WwXC61/EKcrb+yX7gRV4lSWCulZ8JcrAQy8kbxdfY1E/H32zMirffv1fasKOA==", "complaint"=>{"complaint_number"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Complaint", "controller"=>"complaints", "action"=>"create", "product_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>**